# Como usar o bundle.config no webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Gostaria de saber se posso e como usar o `bundle.config` que é utilizado no MVC, no webforms. Fiquei sabendo que há essa possibilidade porém não achei nada na net.
Assim organizaria os CSS e JS num lugar só.

Comment: Olá, Lucas. Tudo bem?
Verifique, por favor, este post em que o autor explica exatamente como usar Bundling e Minification em projetos Web Forms: [Adding Bundling and Minification to Web Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rickandy/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms). Espero ter ajudado. Abraço.